# Move facet_wrap label before y axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
x <- seq(-10, 9.9, by = .1)
y <- seq(0, 19.9, by = .1)
z <- rep(c(1,2,3,4),each=50)

df <- data.frame(col_x = x,
                 col_y = y,
                 col_z = z)
```

and I plot it as such:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = col_x, y = col_y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~col_z, strip.position = "left", nrow = 4)+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle=0))
```

However, in this plot, the facet labels are after the y axis. How do I make it so that the facet labels come before the y axis. In other words, they are further left?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be looking for `theme(strip.placement = "outside")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = col_x, y = col_y))+
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~col_z, strip.position = "left", nrow = 4) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle=0),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

The `strip.placement = "outside"` argument moves the facet labels next to the ticks (which I think is the better placement). So your plot looks like

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! This is perfect. Thank you so much. I am always amazed how many extra parameters there are with ggplot2 I've never heard of.